# Python - get string part from another string

Tags: python, string, replace, split

So I have a string

```
"sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: black;"
```

I want to do some operations on it
I want to change the `#.split.#` part to a div close tag and open tag:

```
str.replace("#.split.#", '</div><div>')
```

other than that i want to take the part after the `style=` and put into that  div open tag

what is a fast procedure to do that?
keep in mind that the `#.split.#style=` part, can occur multiple times in a string, and that the part after the `style=` can vary in length, but always ends in a linebreak.

**edit:**

What i want to achieve is going from a string like this:

```
"sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: black;
 sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: red;"
```

to this:

```
'sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd </div><div style="background: black;">
 sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd </div><div style="background:red;">'
```

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are trying to do -- though it sounds like you want to use `s.split('#.split.#style=')` (where `s` is the string you are processing).

Comment: please print the result you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
import re

text="sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: black\nsdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: red"
matches =  re.findall('.*#.split.#.*', text)
final = ""
for m in matches: 
    parts = re.search("(.*)#.split.#style=(.*)", m) 
    new = '{}</div><div style="{};">'.format(parts.group(1), parts.group(2))
    final += new + "\n"
print final
```

and the result will be:

```
sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd </div><div style="background: black;">
sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd </div><div style="background: red;">
```

Comment: I needed to add a few modifications, to get it working, for my purpose, but it works great. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following what you did,

```
# Avoid str, it is a function name
text = "sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: black;"
text.replace("#.split.#", "</div><div ")
# End the tag
text += ">"
```

This will give a result of:

```
>>> text
"sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd </div><div style=background: black;>"
```

**EDIT**

Just split and rejoin.

```
# Avoid str, it is a function name
text = 'sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: black;\n'
# Split string into sections
text = text.split('\n')
# Do the same thing on each line
for i, s in enumerate(text):
    # Start div tag
    new_text = s.replace('#.split.#', '</div><div ')
    # Add quotes
    new_text = new_text.replace('style=', 'style="')
    new_text = new_text.replace(';', ';"')
    if i != len(text) - 1:
        new_text += '>'
    # Apply changes
    text[i] = new_text
# Join the strings back together with newlines
text = '\n'.join(text)
```

**RE-EDIT**

```
# Avoid str, it is a function name
text = 'sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: black;\nalksjacxnckaljdad#.split.#style=background: white;\n'
# Split string into sections
text = text.split('\n')
# Do the same thing on each line
for i, s in enumerate(text):
    # Start div tag
    new_text = s.replace('#.split.#', '</div><div style="')
    if i != len(text) - 1:
        new_text += '">'
    # Apply changes
    text[i] = new_text
# Join the strings back together with newlines
text = '\n'.join(text)
```

Comment: well it's along the line :) imaging that the string is longer with multiple occurances of the `#.split.#style=` with the css after. so:

text="sdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: black\nsdfsfsdfdsfsdfsd #.split.#style=background: red"

Comment: I want the operations to work on all the `#.split.#style=` parts